# Change all top level directory names to lower case

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to  make a batch that renames only the main folders in the directory to lowercase, not the subfolders inside those folders.

For example:

```
Game\Game Files\Levels
```

Renamed to:

```
game\Game Files\Levels
```

I have tried using jren.bat, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: With the current working directory being the parent of the target directories, have you tried ```@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A:D /B /L 2^>NUL') Do @Ren "%%G" "%%G"``` from your batch file.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't been able to find a working solution online. Works flawlessly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current working directory being the parent of the target directories, you could try the following batch file example:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A:D /B /L 2^>NUL') Do @Ren "%%G" "%%G"
```

To learn how this works, please open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, press the <kbd>[ENTER]</kbd> key, then read the output, paying particular attention to the `/L` option. Next type `for /?`, press the <kbd>[ENTER]</kbd> key, then read the output, particularly that related to the `/F` option. Finally type `ren /?`, press the <kbd>[ENTER]</kbd> key, and see how that command works too.